# HTML5 tags not rendered correctly on Android

Tags: html, xamarin.android

Unable to render html properly on `Android 7.0`, It does not get underlined. Below is the code I used to render:

```
ISpanned displayText;
if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.N)
{
    displayText = Html.FromHtml(item.attributes.attributeLabel, Android.Text.FromHtmlOptions.ModeLegacy);
}
else
{
    displayText = Html.FromHtml(item.attributes.attributeLabel);
}

label.SetText(displayText, TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
```

**HTML**

```
<p style="text-align:center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;"><strong><ins>OFFICE USE ONLY </ins></strong></span></p>
```

I believe that it is because of the `<ins>` tag. Is there anything wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Following are the supported tags in Android Textview using the FromHtml method

Html.fromHtml supports

`<p>`
 `<ul>`
 `<li>`
 `<div>`
 `<span>`
 `<strong>`
 `<b>`
 `<em>`
 `<cite>`
 `<dfn>`
 `<i>`
 `<big>`
 `<small>`
 `<font>`
`<blockquote>`
 `<tt>`
 `<a>`
 `<u>`
 `<del>`
 `<s>`
 `<strike>`
 `<sup>`
 `<sub>`
 `<h1>`
 `<h2>`
 `<h3>` `<h4>`
 `<h5>` `<h6>`
 `<img>`
 `<br>`

Anything other than the following tags is not supported by Android so i guess `<ins>` is causing the issue.